# Anonymous authentication show a popup?

Tags: asp.net, firefox, authentication, anonymous

If you go to [this website](http://mosab2a.elkedeseen.org) using Firefox, you will see a popup window like this:

[image]

If you go the website using google chrome you won't see any popup.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I don't what this popup to be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have included some script which is protected with `Basic Authentication`:

```
<script src="WebServices/LoginService.asmx/jsdebug" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Chrome seems to ignore the Authorization header for it, but FireFox shows this login popup.